# prevent explorer.exe from launching internet explorer

Tags: terminal-server, hardening

In a Windows Terminal Server (2003 R2) where the users are not allowed to run a remote desktop, but just the applications they want (that's Citrix work), i've published "Explorer.exe" for the users to get their files. 
How can i prevent Explorer.exe to launch Internet Explorer when a user writes an url in the address bar instead of a local file path?

Answer (score 2):

`explorer.exe` is silently calling `iexplore.exe` in the background for this. Don't allow these users to launch `iexplore.exe` through Software Restrictions (or any other way really) and it should do the trick.